# Separate data from array to other arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I have data in one big array. Everythink is in one arry, I want to create separate arrays for each gameid beacue this big array has few row with example gameid: 999.

> Object {123: Object { username: tom, gameid: 999 }, 111: Object { username: rob, gameid: 999 }, 222:
>   Object { username: jon, gameid: 1000 }, 333 Object { username: henry, gameid: 1000 }}

I don't have a good idea.

Result should look like:

```
AllGameIdArry [
   array[gameid:999]: [{ username: rob},{ username: tom}]
   array[gameid:1000]: [{ username: rob},{ username: tom}]
   array[gameid:1001]: [{ username: rob},{ username: tom}]
   array[gameid:1002]: [{ username: rob},{ username: tom}]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = {123: { username: `tom`, gameid: 999 }, 111: { username: `rob`, gameid: 999 }, 222: { username: `jon`, gameid: 1000 }, 333: { username: `henry`, gameid: 1000 }}

var final = {};
for (key of Object.keys(x)) {
 if (!final[`gameid:${x[key].gameid}`]) 
    final[`gameid:${x[key].gameid}`] = [];
 final[`gameid:${x[key].gameid}`].push({username: x[key].username});
}
```

Your first example wasn't so good, but i've did something that you might want, at least, to study and do in a better way